# Could there be a delay when using ServiceBusTrigger in Azure functions under consumption plan?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am planning to using [ServiceBusTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) in Azure functions. I know that under Consumption plan, functions might stop running due to inactivity after a certain period of time as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/).

> We deallocate resources after roughly 20 minutes of inactivity, after
>   which your next call will be a cold start

So let's say my function app has been stopped due to inactivity. I understand that a HTTPTrigger will *wake up* my app. It will be slow due to cold start, but at least the delay is only as long as the cold start (few seconds assuming lightweight initialization).

**Questions**

1. How are ServiceBusTriggers handled once an app is deallocated? If a new message comes, will the function get triggered immediately? Cold start penalty is ok, but could it be more like in tens of minutes? This [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#latency-issues) about blob triggers indicate it could take up to 10 minutes, but I am not sure if it applies to Service Bus also.

   > If your function app is on the Consumption plan, there can be up to a
   >   10-minute delay in processing new blobs if a function app has gone
   >   idle.
2. Assuming that there could be delays in tens of minutes, could this be reduced by using Premium plan or App Service Plan with "Always On" set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You are referring to 2 separate triggers: servicebus and blob. Blob triggers are slow, but definitely not tens of minutes. Servicebus triggers are very fast.
2. Yes you can reduce your cold start by going with an app service plan, but I'm not seeing any indication that you would benefit from this. You might save a second or two.

It seems like you are experiencing latency and you are unable to identify the root cause. Triggers are fast.

Comment: Thanks. About #1, does that mean that even when the function app instance has been deallocated due to inactivity, there is still something listening for service bus messages? I brought in the blob comment to describe the fact that blob triggers are also fast when the app is up and running, but not once it gets deallocated. And I am wondering if same can happen for service bus. May be I should test this out :)

Comment: the lag with blob triggered is because the logs of storage account (listing the current blobs in containers) is updated on a time interval, when you are using blob trigger, it actually gets triggered from the log being updated, not directly from the actual blob being created

Comment: im aware of the cold starts with http triggers, however, i'm not sure that there is any lag when it comes to servicebus trigger

Comment: I tested this out. There are no long delays as you mentioned. I see a delay of about 30 seconds, which I think could be due to cold start, though it's still a bit too long for a sample app that does no initializations (it's literally azure function sample app for servicebus triggers). On the other hand, the app with storage queue trigger is actually having much faster cold starts. About ~5 seconds  cold start. Note that, during warm period, service bus trigger is faster than storage queue (1 second vs several seconds).